# Jackson coercing to zero

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs

Using JAX-RS (GlassFish 4) and Jackson as serializer, I encountered a problem during deserialization of POJO properties of type `Double` (same with `Integer`).

Lets say I have simple POJO (excluding bunch of other fieds, getters and setters):

```
public class MapConstraints {    

    private Double zoomLatitude;

    private Double zoomLongitude;   
}
```

When a user send request to API in format `{ "zoomLatitude": "14.45", "zoomLongitude": ""}`, value of `zoomLatitude` is set to `14.45`, but value of `zoomLongitude` is set to `0`.

I expect value of `zoomLongitude` to be `null` if no value is presented. I tried configure `ObjectMapper` with `JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY` but without success.

Same results with genson.

Comment: Do you want to serialize `zoomLongitude` as `null` if it's empty or you don't mind not serializing it?

Comment: The user that sends `""` should get an error message for using your API wrong.

Comment: doesnt matter if it is null or not serialized(default pojo value is null). I know that empty value "" is not valid, but client framework collect values as they are presented in UI and if user dont enter value, an ampty value is sended.

Comment: Try `Include.NON_DEFAULT` instead of `Include.NON_EMPTY`.

Comment: Include.NON_DEFAULT doesn't helped

Comment: I just tried it with latest genson release and it returns null not 0...

Comment: previously I used genson version 1.3. Did you specify some special settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can annotate your POJOs with [`@JsonInclude`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.html) to indicate which values will be (de)serialized:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
private Double zoomLongitude
```

In Jackson 2.6, the following [values](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#enum_constant_summary) are available:

- [`ALWAYS`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#ALWAYS)
- [`NON_ABSENT`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_ABSENT)
- [`NON_DEFAULT`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_DEFAULT)
- [`NON_EMPTY`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_EMPTY)
- [`NON_NULL`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_NULL)
- [`USE_DEFAULTS`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#USE_DEFAULTS)

However, if [`@JsonInclude`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.html) [values](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#enum_constant_summary) don't fit your needs, you can create a custom [`JsonDeserializer`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html):

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Double> {

    @Override
    public Double deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        String text = jp.getText();
        if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return Double.valueOf(text);
        }
    }
}
```

And then just annotate your fields with [`@JsonDeserialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html) indicating the deserializer you want to use:

```
public class MapConstraints {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
    private Double zoomLatitude;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
    private Double zoomLongitude;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this annotation on the POJO:

`@JsonInclude(Include.ALWAYS)`